# html5up! striped with meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, meteor

I'm trying to use a nice responsive site template http://html5up.net/striped and running into a number of problems. I've set up a pretty basic test. I [downloaded](http://html5up.net/striped/download) the striped package, created a clients folder in a meteorite app, and dropped the striped folder in. I had to make two changes
- move the "left-sidebar" class in index.html into a  rather then  as meteor doesn't seem to allow applying classes to bodies.
- move the images into an "img" folder in a public folder

The grid seems offcenter and most of the coloring doesn't load when I run from meteor. However, the striped file on it's own works great (when I load the index.html file directly in my browser rather than through web server). Any idea what is going on here? I played around with it for quite awhile to no avail. I can only think it has to do with how meteor is loading resources but my understanding of how that works didn't lead to any progress for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make some adjustments to the template for it to work with Meteor.

- Create **client** and **public** directories in your meteor root.
- Move **css**, **js**, **images**, **fonts** into **public**.
- In **index.html**, remove `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`, `<html>`, `</html>` tags
- Remove `class="left-sidebar"` from the `<body>` tag.
- Create a new file, **client/init.js** with the following content.

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  $('body').addClass("left-sidebar");
});
```